# Layout inflating again and again on Searching

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-search

I have one Fragment `DefaultMapFragment` which extends Fragment where I'm inflating my layout.

This Fragment is inside an Activity `ActivityMain`.When I do search it seaches in a Activity so layout inflation happens again and again.

Here's my code to describe what I'm doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_geofence_layout);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();

    if(!(mIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)))
    {
        mFragmentManager  = getFragmentManager();

        mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        mTransaction.add(R.id.add_layout, new DefaultMapFragment(),"defaultMapFragment").commit();

        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }


    handleIntent(getIntent());


}
```

So I thought it would be enough to check for the condition if i'm searching but then it does not inflate at all and so my map won't display.

What should I do in this case??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag boolean variable and initially set it to false. when first time you search make it true and in each search just check its status to inflate or not.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new fragment all the time.

Write something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.add_geofence_layout);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
if(!(mIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)))
{
   Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("defaultMapFragment");
 if (fragment == null) {
        mFragmentManager  = getFragmentManager();
mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mTransaction.add(R.id.add_layout, new DefaultMapFragment(),"defaultMapFragment").commit();
mGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }}
handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: Its all the same.Fragment is creating again